# Bash built in Substring

Tags: bash

```
TEXT='Random text 1 and some more random'
TEXT1='Random 19 and more'
TEXT='Anything 7 text text text'
```

I wanted to get everything before the numbers with the numbers included.

Right now, I am able to get the text without the numbers, like so:

```
echo "${TEXT// [0-9]*/}"
```

My question is: is there a way to get what I want with pure Bash built in, like this I am using?

Comment: Why not just `echo $TEXT | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'` or if you want the pipes, `echo $TEXT | awk '{print "|"$1,$2,$3"|"}'`?

Comment: I took off the pipes.

Comment: And edited the question giving more examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "'${TEXT// [^0-9]*/}'" "'${TEXT1// [^0-9]*/}'"
```

Output:

```
'Anything 7' 'Random 19'
```

Note that if the string has *no* numbers, this code will remove everything past the first space.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one cluster of digits you can do it in two steps (in one expansion):

- Remove the longest leading text that ends in a number.

  ```
  $ text='Random 923 and more'
  $ echo "'${text##*[0-9]}'"
  ' and more'
  ```
- Then, remove that selected trailing text from the original string:

  ```
  $ echo "'${text%"${text##*[0-9]}"}'"
  'Random 9'
  ```

That works if the trailing text has no additional numbers.

If could there be several clusters of digits, and you want only the first one, it becomes a bit longer and requires two additional variables.

```
$ text='Random 945 and more 752 numbers'
$ lead=${text%%[0-9]*}
$ trail=${text#"$lead"}
$ echo "'$lead${trail%%[!0-9]*}'"
'Random 945'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bash shell's regular expression matching capability:

```
$ TEXT='Random text 1 and some more random'

$ [[ $TEXT =~ ^[^0-9]*[0-9] ]] && printf '%s\n' "$BASH_REMATCH"
Random text 1
```

where `^[^0-9]*[0-9]` matches zero or more non-digits followed by a digit, anchored to the start of the string

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: Following this leed, I'd use: `echo "grep -o '^[^0-9]*[0-9]' <<< "$TEXT"`. But I am seeking a pure Bash built in...

Comment: I'd love that something like this would work: `cut -d'[0-9]' -f1 <<< "$TEXT"`... But it does not.